# Overlapping multiple CAShapelayers of the same size

Tags: ios, uikit, core-graphics, calayer

In my application, there is a scene that requires overlapping three rounded rectangles, which I implemented through CAShapelayer and UIBezierPath.

Sample code here.

```
[UIColor.green, UIColor.blue, UIColor.yellow].forEach { color in
    let roundPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100), cornerRadius: 25)
    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.path = roundPath.cgPath
    layer.fillColor = color.cgColor
    layer.masksToBounds = true
    layer.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
    view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
}
```

But I found that in the rounded corners of the rounded rectangle, the colors overlap and strange edges appear.

[image]

I want to know the reason for this and how to fix it

Comment: Probably because some of the pixels are partially transparent in the corners to make them appear smoother. Overlapping partially transparent pixels leads to fun new colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CAShapeLayer`'s shape is drawn antialiased by default, and there doesn't appear to be a way to turn this off. Antialiased edges are done by making partially transparent pixels, and you're seeing the effect of stacking transparent pixels in different colours.

Depending on the actual colours you will be using, one fix is to set the stroke colour of the final layer:

```swift
if let shape = view.layer.sublayers?.last as? CAShapeLayer {
    shape.strokeColor = shape.fillColor
}
```